# Questions about Maximum Likelihood Maximization

Tags: maximum-likelihood

(Please excuse potential error, English is nor my first language, nor am I learning stats in english). In my university statistics class, we have been discussing Maximum Likelihood functions, but I am confused as to why we sum over continuous functions as opposed to integrating. I understand that integrating would be useless because we would go right back and derive but it still seems counter intuitive. Not sure if this is a super dumb question but insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you give an example? It's unclear what you are referring to.

Comment: Do you mean summing the log densities over the available sample?

Comment: @Xi;an, yes thats what I mean :)

Comment: because the likelihood of a sample of independent  points is the product of the likelihood of each point. taking logs takes product into sum

Answer (score 0):

This is why, in your situation,

1. You assume each observation is independent. This allows you to compute the joint probability of the data $x_i$ over all the observations $i$ in a sample is the product of each individual sample observation's probability:

$$\prod_{x_{i}} p(x_{i};\theta)$$

2. To

   i. make taking derivatives easier when we symbolically maximize the likelihood

   ii. avoid underflow when numerically maximizing the likelihood

we compute the log-likelihood:

$$ \sum_{x_{i}} {\log(p({x_{i}};\theta))}$$

3. to find the paramter $\theta$ which maximizes the likelhood we usually maximize the negative log likelihood over theta

$$\max_{\theta} \sum_{x_{i}} {-\log(p({x_{i}};\theta))}$$

Comment: Thank you! this was very helpful!

Comment: You are welcome!